# Nested http get request in Angular with flatMap or map

Tags: angular, get, angular-httpclient

I want to produce the following steps in Angular:

1. Get a list of databases  and put it into an observable array
2. Itinerate through the observable and for each element make another http get request (check if a certain table exists)
3. Work with the values afterwards to I can divide the array into several arrays in function of results of the second get request

For information here is the data I get from visiting the URL (JSON):

```
[{"name":"facturation_test"},{"name":"facturation_test2"},{"name":"postgres"},{"name":"source_cadiere"},{"name":"source_dangu"},{"name":"template0"},{"name":"template1"},{"name":"template_urbanisme_7_12"},{"name":"template_urbanisme_7_13"},{"name":"test"},{"name":"urbanisme_asvjl"},{"name":"urbanisme_cadiere"}]
```

Here is what I get from my code till this moment:

My method of the service (database-service.ts)

```
getDatabases():Observable<IDatabase[]>{


    return this.http.get<IDatabase[]>('http://localhost:3000/databases');

}
```

database.component.ts

```
//My variable stocking the info (type interface:IDatabase[])
public databases:IDatabase[];
```

Inside my onInit method after importing the service

```
this._datebaseServiceService.getDatabases()
  .subscribe(
    data=>{
      this.databases= data;
      console.log(this.databases);
    });
```

Inside my second service table-countService.ts

```
getTableCount(databasename, tableName):Observable<ICount[]>{

    return this.http.get<ICount[]>('http://localhost:3000/check-table? 
database='+databasename+'&tablename='+tableName);

  }
```

I have tried several approaches from `.flatMap` and `.map` but I just couldn't get the syntax right. I also tried to simply iterate over the `this.database` variable, but if I do that I will have nested subscribes as I don't know how to call it otherwise. Even after several lectures of explanations of those two commands I still have some problems with flatMap.

As far I have understood the following:

- `.map` => goes over each element of an observable and is (I think) what I need here
- `.flatMap` => seems to be used for nested request, but I don't get how it goes over each element?

I'm clearly missing something as retrieving the data itself (list of tables) hasn't been a problem.

Comment: `.map` takes a callback that accepts a single value from the stream and returns the new value for everything downstream to receive. `.flatMap` takes a callback that accepts a single value of the stream and returns **an observable of the new value** for everything downstream to receive. That's it; `.flatMap` just unrolls one level of observable.

Comment: First, thanks for editing the answer, I didn't know how to add different blocks of code. Second, how could I add the flatMap method to my code? In the service method or the component method? @jonsharpe